# Private prototype methods that can share scope and access the instance

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, prototype, private, private-members

I'm looking for a pattern that both allows me to create a private scope that my function prototype has access to and I need to be able to access the instance from within that scope.

For example, this is how I am currently achieving "private methods" (disregard what the code actually does, just look at the structure.)

```
function InfoPreview() {
   this.element = document.createElement('div');
}

//Private Methods
InfoPreview.prototype.__newLine = function () {
  this.element.appendChild(createElement({tagName:'br'}));
}; 

InfoPreview.prototype.__padLeft = function(level) {
  var padding = createElement({tagName: 'span'});
  this.element.appendChild(padding);
  $(padding).width(level * 10);
};

InfoPreview.prototype.__print = function(string) {
  var span = createElement({ tagName: 'span', textContent: string });
  this.element.appendChild(span);
  this.element.style["margin-right"]='10px';
};

InfoPreview.prototype.__puts = function(string) {
  this.__print(string);
  this.__newLine();
};

//Public Methods
InfoPreview.prototype.update = function(info) {
  $(this.element).empty();
  for (var record in info) {
    this.__puts(record);
  }
};
```

Notice that I am not creating private methods at all, just utilizing a naming convention. Additionally notice that I have no way to cache chain-lookups, such as `this.element`.

I would like to create a private scope by utilizing a revealing module pattern, like this:

```
InfoPreview.prototype = (function() {
  var self = this, //<- `this` is actually the global object now.
      el = self.element;

  var newLine = function () {
    el.appendChild(createElement({tagName:'br'}));
  }; 

  var padLeft = function(level) {
    var padding = createElement({tagName: 'span'});
    el.appendChild(padding);
    $(padding).width(level * 10);
  };

  var print = function(string) {
    var span = createElement({ tagName: 'span', textContent: string });
    el.appendChild(span);
    el.style["margin-right"]='10px';
  };

  var puts = function(string) {
    print(string);
    newLine();
  };

  var update = function(info) {
    $(el).empty();
    for (var record in info) {
      puts(record);
    }
  };

  return {
    update: update
  }; 
})();
```

The above approach doesn't work however, because the value of `this` within the IIFE is the global object, not the instance. I need a way to access the instance.

Comment: When you call `instance.update(info)`, you'll have access to `this`. You can either explicitly pass it to the private functions, or else invoke them with `.call()` to set `this`.

Comment: @Pointy Ahh, so that would give me access to the instance within each function, but do you know of a good way to cache the lookups that are rooted at the instance and share them among *all* of the functions? (Rather than having to repeat the same init code in multiple functions)

Comment: Well one way or the other you're going to be juggling the instance reference. I don't know that the concept of "caching" really makes sense; there's just one closure for those functions, not one per instance.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah, I think you're right.  I suppose I could make getter functions  for the longer chains and cache the results within the getter functions themselves (as a sub-optimal solution)

Comment: what do you mean by cache?

Comment: @Tivie in regards to my last comment, I mean function caching (a.k.a. memoization). In regards to the way I used it in my question, I just mean "saving the value" e.g.    typing `el` rather than `this.element`. It is faster for both my fingers and the processor. A better word might have been 'alias'.

Comment: @LukeP is there any issue with using a function pattern?

Comment: @LukeP, you can't cache `this` and `this.element` on this level because then it cached one value for all instances, you can just past current `this` or `element` as a simple parameter like `var padLeft = function(el, level) {` and call `padLeft(this.element)`

Comment: @Grundy Yes, I understand that. That's why I was looking for an alternative pattern. I was hoping I could find a good way to share a single reference to the instance, and to share references to  nested instance variables as well among the functions. (I now realize that a good solution will be harder to implement than I originally thought)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any downside of using a constructor pattern?

```js
function Foo(constructorArg) {
    
    /* private variables */
    var privVar = 'I am private',
        cArg = constructorArg;
    
    /* public variables */
    this.pubVar = 'I am public';
    
    /* private function */
    function privFunc() {
        return 'I am a private function';
        
    }
    
    /* public function */
    this.publicFunc = function() {
        return 'I am a public function and I call privVar->"' + privVar + '" and privFunc->"' + privFunc() + '"';
    }
}

var foo = new Foo('something');

console.log('foo.pubVar', foo.pubVar); //ok
console.log('foo.publicFunc()', foo.publicFunc()); // ok

console.log('foo.privVar', foo.privVar); // undefined
console.log('foo.privFunc', foo.privFunc()); //error
```

## Why you should use it (as requested in comments):

Simply put, because it is the only (sane) way of creating a "true private scope", which was your question.

The alternative is using a convention which tell developers what properties and methods are private, usually by prefixing them with an underscore `_`, which you already implemented but disliked.

Note that constructor and prototype are different things and enable you to do different stuff. Nothing prevents you from mixing both up.

### Memory usage

Regarding memory usage, in modern js engines, such as Google's V8 JavaScript Engine, [the constructor pattern might actually be faster](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/#toc-topic-hiddenclasses).

> V8 has hidden types created internally for objects at runtime; objects with the same hidden class can then use the same optimized generated code.

For example:

```
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

var p1 = new Point(11, 22);
var p2 = new Point(33, 44);
// At this point, p1 and p2 have a shared hidden class
p2.z = 55;
// warning! p1 and p2 now have different hidden classes!
```

Prototype chaining always require two lookups, so it might even be a tiny inny LITTLE bit slower. **Note: Can't back up on this, jsperf.com is down!**

### Constructor pattern is dirty (sic)

> Performance was my reason. I hadn't realized that. However it still feels dirty to me

I don't know why you feel the constructor pattern is dirty. Maybe it's because it has some "specifics", limitations and potential pitfalls you should be aware

1. `this` can mean different things
2. It's easy to forget the new keyword causing weird and hard to debug bugs due to shared state
3. You can't easily split your object across multiple files (without resorting to a build tool or some 3rd party injector)

However, 1 and 2 are also true for prototype declaration style so...

if you feel this is not adequate, you might want to look at the module pattern.

Comment: Can you figure out a way to adapt this so I can use this pattern with my prototype methods? (I can't)

Comment: Not without an extremely overcomplicated anti-pattern. Why do you need to use prototype?

Comment: Thats just what I need for this use case. I'm looking for a general pattern that I can use with my instance methods. I don't want to copy the methods to each individual instance.      It does appear that the only way to have my cake and eat it too is going to be to write my own mini-framework that allows the private functions to register dependencies with a mechanism in the outer scope. (that is more work than I'm looking to do though)

Comment: I don't understand... You don't need to copy the methods to each individual instance. Each instance of Foo has the methods you assigned in the constructor.

Comment: I didn't mean manually, I just don't want them copied. I want them to share the same methods.

Comment: Which begs the question, Why? The reason I'm asking is because most often people say it's about performance. While is true prototype pattern is generally faster that `this` pattern, it is barely noticeable unless you instantiate a LOT (and I mean, a LOT like 10K) objects per script runs.
Also, new Javascript engines use "hidden classes". Check http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/

Comment: Regardless of the reason, however, what you ask is impossible because you want a closure to be in the correct "object instance scope" implicitly (which requires instantion in each call) without sharing state between instances. It's like asking for a class "static" method to behave as an object "dynamic" method.

Comment: Performance was my reason. I hadn't realizes that. However it still feels dirty to me.

Comment: I understand that what I asked in its current form is impossible, that's why I asked for an alternative pattern. Yours is an alternative, just not the type of alternative i originally envisioned. If you append an explanation of WHY I should use this pattern, in the question itself. ill probably accept it

Comment: I've been looking into this more and I've actually run into some talks by Dave Crockford where he recommends ditching prototypes, citing the same performance reasons you state here. He utilizes a revealing module pattern in his constructor and returns a frozen object.

Comment: Regarding your  "specifics" as well, considering your argument, you don't even need prototypes at all anymore, so you can ditch `new` all together. In regards to `this`: the beauty of this pattern is that, in the top level scope `this` does point to the instance! So, you can alias this with something like `self` or `that` and then the private functions will "close over" that variable.

Answer (score 1):

*Within* each function, you will have access to the `this` value you want.

```js
var Example = function() {};

Example.prototype = (function() {
  var privateUpdate = function() {
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = this.foo;
  }
  
  return {
    update: privateUpdate
  }
})();

var e = new Example();
e.foo = 'bar';
e.update();
```

```html
<div id="answer"></div>
```

Comment: After testing, you still need to either use `call` or pass `this` explicitly when calling the private functions from within other private functions. Additionally, I cant share state between the private functions with this alone

Answer (score 1):

As a variant on what Pointy is suggesting, you can try this pattern;

```
infoPreview.prototype = (function() {
  var self = null;

  var update = function(info) {
      ....
  };

  var firstUpdate = function(info) {
      self = this;
      functions.update = update;
      update(info);  
  }

  var functions = {
    update: firstUpdate
  }; 
  return functions;
})();
```

Comment: I was thinking this as well, although this becomes a lot of (possibly unnecessary) re-computation as the number of methods and the number instance variables I need access to increases.

Comment: this also not working for a few objects, because after call for first object - it cached and used for second object

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that, without prototyping :

https://jsfiddle.net/ynwun1xb

```
var Fn = function(el) {
    this.el = el;

    var myMethod = function() {
        console.log('do something in method with element', this.el);
    }.bind(this);

    return {
        myPublicMethod: function() {
            return myMethod();
        }
    }
}

var instancedFn = new Fn('first instance element')
    .myPublicMethod()
;

var instancedFn2 = new Fn('second instance element')
    .myPublicMethod()
;
```